# Why is static final slower than a new on each iteration

Tags: java, performance, static

Why is code snippet A 14x slower than code snippet B?
(tested with jdk1.8.0_60 on Windows 7 64bits)

*Code snippet A:*

```
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

public class Test {
    private static final RoundRectangle2D.Double RECTANGLE = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = RECTANGLE.hashCode();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            result += RECTANGLE.hashCode();            // <= Only change is on this line
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

*Code snippet B:*

```
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

public class Test {
    private static final RoundRectangle2D.Double RECTANGLE = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = RECTANGLE.hashCode();
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {
            result += new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).hashCode();
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

TL;DR: Using the `new` keyword inside a loop is faster than accessing a `static final` field.

(note: Removing the `final` keyword on `RECTANGLE` does not change the execution time)

Comment: Your testing doesn't take into account JVM warm-up time/startup time. Your results will probably be inconsistent as-written. You're really testing how quickly the JVM starts up, and then executes your code.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, JVM warm-up / startup is certainly a consideration, but it does not explain the performance difference I see for the OP's codes.  Even after inserting a warm-up loop into the slower one, the (improved) performance does not come close to faster one.

Comment: no, I tried this by running case A then case B within one application, and then reversing the order, an in both cases, case A was 21x longer

Comment: interestingly, I find that the integer addition is taking up the vast majority of this time. If you adjust the loop to not add to the result, but still make the call to hashcode, the results drop to only a factor of 3x, but is about 30x faster than with the summation.

Comment: Decompile it and examine the byte code differences. This may also be compiler-dependent (and OP did not specify which compiler, although I suppose we can assume Oracle)

Comment: @PaulOstrowski the addition is there to make sure the JVM cannot optimize away the entire call and that the CPU can't use its cache.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Yes, I used Oracle's compiler and did de-compile it, the decompiled code is exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: Running in interpreted mode (-Xint) the picture changes drastically. Most likely case B is recognized by the JIT as the object not escaping and mostly optimized away.

Comment: @qwertzguy If it were truly exactly the same, then there would be no difference. Something is different in the byte code, perhaps you're just missing it.

Comment: I tried a version that instantiates the rectangle inside the method, but outside the loop, holds its reference only in a local variable, and re-uses that instead repeatedly instantiating new ones.  That helped slightly (about 10% improvement), but the result is still much slower.

Comment: There is some odd optimization that doesn't get applied when it's static final, and seemingly only slowly when it's a local variable: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/adc308599c5547e0057b504e89fa1f35 - I guess the jvm can deduct that the hash isn't changing and simply inlines it.

Comment: Also, warming up the fast version sped it up by about 60%.

Comment: -XX:CompileThreshold=0 and things turn out as one expects, A faster than B. Its JIT optimization magic.

Comment: @SnakeDoc -_- no, I said exactly the same in **both** cases, meaning that decompiled code of snippet A is same as snippet A and decompiled code of snippet B is same as snippet B, but they don't compile to the same code.

Comment: @Durandal It's pretty obvious that it's the result of JIT optimization. My question is why is snippet A not optimized to run as fast or faster? Almost seems like a bug of the JVM to me.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I don't believe it's an issue of JVM warm-up. If you add a 0 to the loop, the difference becomes 78x. It's clearly that in one case the JIT compiler optimizes it and in the other it fails to do so. Basically, the time almost doesn't change when adding a 0 for code snippet B, and for code snippet A it seems to change linearly.

Comment: @qwertzguy for that the JVM would have to prove somehow that the result of `hashCode` will not change if it is invoked multiple times. That would at least imply proving that in addition to always yielding the same result for the same initial state, `hashCode` also does not mutate any fields - it seems that the JIT does not go that far (yet?). (Writing a mutating hashCode would of course be a horrible idea, but...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the first case (static final) JVM needs to read object fields from memory.
In the second case the values are known to be constant. Furthermore, since the object does not escape from the loop, the allocation is eliminated, e.g. its fields are replaced with local variables.

The following [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark supports the theory:

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StaticRect {
    private static final RoundRectangle2D.Double RECTANGLE =
            new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    @Benchmark
    public long baseline() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long testNew() {
        return new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).hashCode();
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(jvmArgs = "-XX:-EliminateAllocations")
    public long testNewNoEliminate() {
        return new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).hashCode();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testStatic() {
        return RECTANGLE.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
StaticRect.baseline            avgt   10   2,840 ± 0,048  ns/op
StaticRect.testNew             avgt   10   2,831 ± 0,011  ns/op
StaticRect.testNewNoEliminate  avgt   10   8,566 ± 0,036  ns/op
StaticRect.testStatic          avgt   10  12,689 ± 0,057  ns/op
```

`testNew` is as fast as returning a constant, because object allocation is eliminated and the `hashCode` is constant-folded during JIT compilation.

When `EliminateAllocations` optimization is disabled, the benchmark time is notably higher, but the arithmetic calculations of `hashCode` are still constant-folded.

In the last benchmark, even though `RECTANGLE` is declared final, its fields could be in theory changed, so JIT cannot eliminate field access.

Comment: By _constant-folded_, you mean that the various `RoundRectangle2D.Double` fields are extracted into local variables and the `hashCode` is calculated on those, eventually figuring out that it always returns the same value? Presumably, you could break all this by changing one of the constructor arguments to be a calculated variable (that evaluates to 2 for the sake of this example)?

Comment: So in the last benchmark, the only reason why it can't optimize is because changes to RECTANGLE's fields could be done by another thread?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, JIT realizes that all operands of the expression are constant, thus the expression is also constant. If you add a variable, the expression will be calculated in run-time, but this will not necessarily require memory loads.

Comment: @qwertzguy RECTANGLE object is out of local context; HotSpot usually does not eliminate field access of objects that may escape from a local scope. Though this is not absolutely impossible, but such optimizations are rather difficult and not usually worthy.

Comment: Well, all in all it means that putting things as static final rather than making a new instance each time can be slower (when the constructor is fast), which makes it much harder to have a well defined best practice.

Comment: @apangin actually it gets even more weird: in Snippet B, if I make a local variable just above the `for` loop with the `new Round[...]` and use it in the loop, it becomes just as slow as Snippet A.

Comment: @qwertzguy Because it's not a correct benchmark. What you measure is the [OSR stub](http://xmlandmore.blogspot.ru/2012/06/on-stack-replacement-in-hotspot-jvm.html). It's usually unrelated to the real application performance. To measure an optimized method you need to call it several times.